# XSL-FO - Last-page number after a variable number of independent page sequencies

Tags: xsl-fo

I want to get the last-page number after a series of independent page sequences without introducing an extra page at the end of the document. Currently I have to add an extra page sequence with one `<fo:block id="last-page"/>` which generates an extra empty page. This is the idea:

```
<xsl:call-template name="a-block-with-its-own-page-sequence"/>

<xsl:if test="//SOMETHING-2-EXISTS = 'Y'">
  <xsl:call-template name="a-block-with-its-own-page-sequence-page-number-continues"/>
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="//SOMETHING-3-EXISTS = 'Y'">
  <xsl:call-template name="a-block-with-its-own-page-sequence-page-number-continues"/>
</xsl:if>

<!-- 
   and more blocks with its own page sequences here 
-->

<!-- Currently I have to do this which create an extra page -->
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="lastOneForSure">
    <xsl:call-template name="header_footer"/>
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:block id="last-page"/>
    </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
```

Comment: Are SOMETHING-2 and SOMETHING-3 elements with different names? Or just multiple occurrences of the same element name, e.g. `<chapter> `

Answer (score 0):

`fo:page-citation-last` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_page-number-citation-last) will get you the last page produced by the areas from an FO.

If every `fo:page-sequence` has an ID, then you only need to work out which ID to use for the `fo:page-citation-last/@ref-id` value.

Comment: Working out which ID to use is the difficult part. XSLT does not have a way to have a variable that can be overwritten to keep track of the latest value after a series of if statements.

Comment: It doesn't, but you could put an `xsl:variable` around all of those `xsl:call-template` to get all of the interesting `fo:page-sequence`.  You could then either use an XPath on the variable to get the ID of the last `fo:page-sequence` or, alternatively, transform the value of the variable to add a known ID to the last `fo:page-sequence`.  You would then also copy the variable (or its transformed value) to the result.  (All of this would be easier with XSLT 2.0 or XSLT 3.0 than if you are still using XSLT 1.0.)

Answer (score 0):

You may be going about this the wrong way round.

If you do this:

```
<template match="SOMETHING-2|SOMETHING-3">
    <fo:page-sequence>
```

you can get rid of the `<xsl:if test="//SOMETHING-2-EXISTS = 'Y'">` construction.

The next step is figuring out which is the last chapter. Can you use position()? That depends on what SOMETHING-2|SOMETHING-3 are. If they are elements with different names, it's more difficult, but if they're just multiple occurrences of the same element name, e.g.  you can use position().

Comment: Where in XSL 1.1 does it say that you can use `fo:page-number-citation-last` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_page-number-citation-last) without a `ref-id` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#ref-id)?

Comment: I was going by this, see the third code sample: https://www.alt-soft.com/tutorial/xslfo_tutorial/xsl-fo_page-number.html

Comment: If it's an extension, it's undocumented, otherwise the sample could just be wrong.  `ref-id` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#ref-id) is required to have a value, which is a roundabout way of saying that the property is required to be present.

Comment: You're right, I tested with AHF and without a ref-id, I get an error "Missing required property value: 'ref-id'".